Startup Disk Creator doesn't create an extra `writable` partition as it used to
Something strange.
2 days ago, I used Startup Disk Creator (SDC) to prepare a USB Drive for an Ubuntu 24.04.1 install (on my 22.04). The USB stick is a USB-C (USB 3) 64GB drive.
That created the usual bootable Ubuntu install partition + another ext4 partition named writable using the remaining space, that's convenient to move data using that extra partition.
Today I used again SDC on a USB-A (USB 3) 32 GB drive (still on my 22.04). But this time it didn't use the remaining space (~23GB) to create a writable partition. The 23 GB is lost.
So I thought it's maybe because 32 GB is too "small", or maybe because it's USB-A...
To be sure, I erased the initial 64 GB USB-C drive (dd...)  and run SDC again ...
This time it didn't create the writable partition anymore...
Are there other criteria to consider (or it's random??)
-- edit --

I realize that maybe (don't remember) I only mounted the USB drive on the newly installed 24.04.1 system (thanks to that drive), and 24.04 may show a partition that 22.04 doesn't?

Or, another possibility, the writable partition is created on the USB drive during the install?


Can someone please confirm 1. or 2. (or ...)

One vote for 2. from me.

Not sure what you are expecting to achieve here. The Ubuntu Disc Creator utility is meant to flash a USB drive (usually with a single Ubuntu .iso) installation or try Ubuntu media. If you are looking for a bootable USB where you can simple copy multiple .iso files across, you need to consider using Ventoy
